# Идиомы, связанные с едой

Tags: idioms

В домашнем задании попросили привести примеры идиом, свзяанных с едой. Вспомнилось следующее:

- Ест так, что за ушами свистит
- Ну ты и фрукт
- Съесть вместе пуд соли
- Он на этом собаку съел

a) являются ли эти примеры идиомами и б) какие еще могут быть примеры подобных идиом?

Comment: Из того что пришло в голову: "ни рыба, ни мясо", "не фунт изюму", "вешать лапшу на уши".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"За ушами *трещит*", а не "*свистит*" (во всяком случае, лично я вторую форму никогда не встречал).

Идиомами вроде бы называются только неделимые сочетания, т.е. "собаку съесть", а не "он на этом собаку съел". Соответственно, в предыдущем примере "фрукт" - это не идиома, а другое (переносное) значение слова.

Примеры навскидку: птичье молоко; молочные реки и кисельные берега.

P.S. Как мёдом намазано, как сыр в масле кататься.

Comment: трещит vs свистит, думаю, региональное. я слышал обе. спасибо.

Comment: "За ушами свистит" есть:   http://www.interpal.info/index.php/term/,9da4ab975b5460a09c5559675e9f64639e6e6d5a56a96465a85a5967549fa25a716da7a3a75d5aac66675ba06a9ea954a65897626da89e69a26d.xhtml

Answer (score 3):

Идиома - это фраза, чье значение не сводится напрямую к значениям её составных частей. 
Соответственно, вопрос можно понимать двояко. С едой может быть связано "новое" значение идиомы:

- заморить червячка

Или исходное значение составляющих идиому слов:

- искать клубничку
- испить чашу
- не солоно хлебавши (несолоно хлебавши)
- не по зубам

Comment: не по зубам - это не с едой, а скорее с укусами

Comment: "Испить чашу [до дна]" - библейская цитата, так же как и, к примеру, "манна небесная".

Answer (score 3):

- на хлеб (в контексте "зарабатывать на хлеб", иногда чуть иронично - "на хлеб с маслом")
- как не в себя (ест как не в себя)
- чёрным по красному (подразумевается чёрной икрой по красной - означает высшую степень достатка)
- порубить в капусту (мелко нарезать, чаще всего оппонентов)
- сытый голодного не разумеет (не понимает)
- кашу маслом не испортишь
- каши просит (прохудилось, разорвалось - в отношении обуви)
- нажраться в хлам (сильное алкогольное опьянение)
- хлеб с солью (встречать с хлебом-солью)
- когда я ем я глух и нем (не говорить во время еды)
- чепуха на постном масле
- кормить завтраками
- на убой (кормить как на убой - то есть до объедения)
- пальчики оближешь (вкусно)
- масло масленное (повтор, тавтология)
- горе луковое (не настоящая проблема)
- как мёдом намазано (очень сильно кого-то притягивает - обычно неодобрительно)
- не первой свежести (протухшее)

Answer (score 2):

- иметь свой кусок хлеба (с маслом)
- кусок в горло не лезет